# How can I create a program or bookmarklet that can scrape facebook-chat messages for spam links?

Tags: html, facebook, web-scraping, automation, facebook-chat

There is a Facebook app which has enabled the depricated facebook-chat feature where users can chat whilst playing their game. Unfortunately there has been a dirge of spammers and scammers posting in this chatroom, which we would wish to automatically detect and send emails or some other alerts to us so that we can more immediately block/ban these users.

Is this possible somehow? What we've tried was to create a python scraping application but it wasn't immediately obvious how to log into facebook and get HTML of an app through a python call.

I've since been introduced to bookmarklets as a concept. Perhaps this could solve the issue? There could be some type of javascript code in a bookmarklet, and all one would need to do is load up the game, open the facebook-chat, and then click the bookmarklet, and leave the computer running 24-7. The javascript would parse the DOM for suspected scam links and send email reminders when found.

This is just me brainstorming possible ideas. I'm really not sure how to approach this automation problem, and I am not finding anything useful online either.

Comment: Scraping will only get one entity banned/blocked in the end ... and that's you. Apart from that, not sure what chat feature you're actually referring to here.

Comment: @CBroe https://imgur.com/a/qHUML see this link. This is the live chat I am referring to. It is a depricated but still existing feature of facebook games, where users can chat with the community of players.

Banned? Really? Maybe my definition of scraping is not so correct. What I'm talking should be a very passive thing. It would simply view the HTML of an already opened tab and then scan for spam/scam messages in a particular div/class.

Comment: Don't try to login to a facebook account using any kind of scripts, that is considered unwanted automation/scraping. I doubt a bookmarklet would still work, I think CSP has put pretty much an end to those on any major sites.  If anything, I could see this working in a browser extension (that you then just would have to keep running in some browser instance with a logged-in account), that should be able to actually inject JavaScript into the page.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for that other option, either some sort of bookmarklet, or as you say, a browser extension. Not a script. I fully intend to keep it running in some browser instance. If you could provide a few more details, please and thank you. Maybe there is a tool I could hook onto so that creating such an extension is simple. I've never made an extension before and my JS skills are weak.